# Hide Status Bar without using FLAG_FULLSCREEN

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to hide the Status Bar in my app and maintain the ability for the virtual keyboard to adjustResize for ScrollViews.

This:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

does not work because it breaks all ScrollViews preventing the `adjustResize` from resizing the view allowing the user to scroll when the keyboard is visible, so this is not an acceptable answer.

I've got:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

In my base theme, and I tried putting that setting directly into the Manifest entry for my activity, but it doesn't do anything.

I am using ActionBarSherlock in my app so I can provide a uniform UI to my users and it requires that I use one of three base themes:

> In order for the custom action bar implementation to function your
>   application must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, or
>   Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or your custom theme must use one
>   of the aforementioned as its parent.

So, I've configured my Theme this way:

```
<style name="LightNoTitleBar" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and I've got `android:theme="@style/LightNoTitleBar"` in my manifest entry for this activity.

So, how can I hide the status bar given the above restrictions?