# Content under Status Bar on Android without FLAG_FULLSCREEN

Tags: android

This has been asked before [without answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463975/hide-status-bar-without-using-flag-fullscreen)

To render an Android app under the status bar every single resource out there points me towards doing:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This works, but then causes problems with content rendering under the keyboard which makes it impossible to use forms.

[image]

This is as far as I can scroll down, a couple of inputs and the submit button are covered by the keyboard

Is there another Android API to render the app under the status bar that I'm missing? I know apps that have done this so it must be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please just try this way with

android:windowsoftinputmode adjust resize/adjustpan/statevisible/stateHidden etc..   in activity tag inside manifest file

Or.    Inside activity

getwindow().setsoftinputmode(Windowmanage.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)

and manage the layout with scrollview

Hope it may help you

Comment: Unfortunately the API for `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` says `If the window's layout parameter flags include FLAG_FULLSCREEN, this value for softInputMode will be ignored; the window will not resize, but will stay fullscreen.` It doesn't work.

Comment: also try with scrollview parent layout with or without fillviewport attribute hope it may help

Comment: Any advice on how to use those?

Comment: add <scrollview fillviewport true> child layout here with </scrooview> in your layout.xml file,. you can also try with nestedscrollview if not work so read from https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the WindowInsetsCompat API
[documantation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsCompat)
WindowsInsetsCompat is available from **androidx.core:core:1.5.0** (or **androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0**)

Release notes [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core):

Version 1.5.0

- Backported WindowInsetsController and WindowInsetsCompat APIs to control system bar appearance

Comment: I have tried setting `layoutInDisplayCutoutMode` to `LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES` but nothing seemed to happen. Is there anything else I'm missing here? Do you have an example?